# How to access JS file api in angular component.ts file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one function in js file under src/server/js/controller.js, and I want to use that API inside component's ts file. I wrote the following code to do same but seems not working

**controller.js**

```
const getDomainName= (hostName) => {
    console.log('hostName get controller', hostName); 
}
module.exports = {getDomainName};
```

**flush-component.ts**

```
import {getDomainName} from '../../../../server/controllers/controller.js';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LaunchUtil {
   //How to call from here
}
```

Note: I should not put this file under assets folder since it is referring by other JS files.

Answer (score 0):

You should export it like this:

```
const getDomainName= (hostName) => {
    console.log('hostName get controller', hostName); 
}
export { getDomainName }
```

And use it anywhere in your application project using `import` syntax:

```
import { getDomainName } from '../../../../server/controllers/controller.js';
```

Comment: Can you explain bit briefly? should i use export instead of module.export. and how can i import that module in component.ts file and can use

Comment: it related to ES6 module management system. In Angular project bootstrapped using Angular-CLI, we have to use this syntax cause it's the way Angular team implemented. For more information: [Import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) & [Export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)